# SQL - search multiple columns from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select all the team from USA that have a match (participate) after '2022-01-02' ?

event table.

| home_team | away_team | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | BBB | 2022-01-01 |
| AAA | FFF | 2022-01-01 |
| BBB | CCC | 2022-01-02 |
| AAA | HHH | 2022-01-05 |
| RRR | AAA | 2022-01-05 |
| QQQ | BBB | 2022-01-09 |

stat table.

| team_name | country | match_played |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | USA | 49 |
| BBB | France | 22 |
| CCC | Canada | 32 |
| DDD | USA | 25 |
| EEE | Italy | 20 |
| FFF | Germany | 90 |
| GGG | France | 62 |
| HHH | USA | 25 |

Answer (score 0):

Join the `event` table to the `stat` table twice, and then check the match date:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE s1.country WHEN 'USA'
        THEN e.home_team ELSE e.away_team END AS team
FROM event e
INNER JOIN stat s1 ON s1.team_name = e.home_team
INNER JOIN stat s2 ON s2.team_name = e.away_team
WHERE s1.country = 'USA' OR s2.country = 'USA' AND
      e.date > '2022-01-02';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT team_name FROM `tb2` WHERE `country` = 'USA' 
AND team_name IN 
(SELECT home_team FROM tb1 WHERE date > '2022-01-02'
UNION
SELECT away_team FROM tb1 WHERE date > '2022-01-02')
```

First, we fetch the team name who have a match (participate) after '2022-01-02' then select the USA team only.
[image]